# display a warning message visible on every page

Tags: development

Occasionally we would like to display a warning message on our Sharepoint site, for example to warn in advance users of scheduled downtime or that the site is temporarly overloaded.
This message should be easily configurable and should display on each page, for example at the top of the page.

What would be the simplest, least intrusive way to do it ?

Thanks
Michele

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'The way' to do it is to put user or delegate control on your masterpage. This control can then display your message on every single page.

You can add some additional logic eg. your control can check some list on root site to see if some announcement exist or something similar. If you take this path you need to be extra careful because if you use custom control in masterpage it will load on every page so running some complex code can lead to different performance issues.

Take a look at this for a start:

[Make Your SharePoint 2010 Master Page Extensible with Delegate Controls](http://fyeomans.com/2011/05/16/make-your-sharepoint-2010-master-page-extensible-with-delegate-controls/)

Comment: I was hoping for a solution which did not impact the master pages, anyway thanks a lot, I will look into that.

Comment: castigli, what do you mean as "impact"? As Vedran suggests you can use delegate control (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms463169.aspx). You don't need to alter master page in any way and it's the strength of delegate controls. All you need is to choose right delegate control to substitute. In your case it's convenient to use AdditionalPageHead placeholder: http://littletalk.wordpress.com/2010/11/18/create-an-additionalpagehead-control-packed-into-a-feature-in-visual-studio-2010/

Comment: ...thanks for the clarification Alex, I jumped incorrectly to conclusions without fully understanding the article.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need a status bar: http://geekswithblogs.net/venkatx5/archive/2010/11/18/how-to-use-status-bar-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx

Comment: From the point of view of the layout, this is exactly was I thinking. I will try to put this stuff in the master pages as suggested below Thanks